# etree import not working- Python 2.7.5

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to use elementtree to parse xml but the import is giving me an error.

**No module named etree**

I've tried :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

I have elementtree downloaded in my python library on mac. Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What happens when you try this on the python command line?  Have you done a homebrew install?

Comment: "No module named etree" is the error I get. I haven't tried a homebrew install. I installed it from the setup.py file I downloaded from elementtree. How would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ElementTree is a part of the standard Python library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), you shouldn't need to install anything to get it to work.

Using a [standard install from IdeOne, shows your first line works, with no extra libraries](https://ideone.com/Ywik3H).

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
print ET
```

gives:

> Success    time: 0.03 memory: 44896 signal:0
>
> ```
> <module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' from '/usr/lib/pypy/lib-python/2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py'>
> ```

Something has gone wrong with your install, or you are trying to use a [third party library like lXML](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

---

Alternatively, [you have a file named xml.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10324708/764357) in your project that is overriding your Python install. You can check this by running the following code in your file *before* any other imports.

```
import xml
print xml.__file__
```

If the path doesn't look like this, and shows a path to your local project thats your problem.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but when I use "from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET" It still gives me the error  "No module named etree". I do have elementtree in my python folder though.

Comment: Yes. Your install has gone wrong. That code should work on a standard python 2 or 3 install. Uninstall python, reinstall from an official source and try again.

Comment: @user3553851 There is one other possible issue, check my update.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any local file named xml and also remove their compiled versions. Python initially searches for xml locally  and hence conflict might occur.