# Python 2.7.16 - ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, import, element, elementtree

I am making a script to perform creating and writing data to XML file. The error is no module no module name

I refer to this stackoverflow link, [Python 2.5.4 - ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073033/python-2-5-4-importerror-no-module-named-etree-elementtree). I refer to this tutorial, https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/. I still do not understand on what is the solution. I tried to replace

"from elementtree import ElementTree"

to

"from xml.etree import ElementTree"

It still did not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
root = xml.Element("FOLDER")

child = xml.Element("File")

root.append(child)

fn = xml.SubElement(child, "PICTURE")
fn.text = "he32dh32rf43hd23"
md5 = xml.SubElement(child, "CONTENT")
md5.text = "he32dh32rf43hd23"

tree = xml.ElementTree(root)
with open(xml.xml, "w") as fh:
   tree.write(fh)
```

"""
I expect the result to be that data is written to xml file. But I received an error shown below,

````
  File "./xml.py", line 2, in <module>
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
  File "/root/Desktop/virustotal/testxml/xml.py", line 2, in <module>
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
```ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
````

Comment: You are writing your own `xml` module and hiding the one in the stadard library.

Comment: Apologies. I did not copy the import xml module. However, after I added the import module it still did not work.Please kindly advise.

Comment: Do not call your file `xml.py`.

Comment: It is a name. What are the risk in calling the file xml.py

Comment: I already told you, you are hiding the module with the same name in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

`import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml`

and make sure you have the `__init__.py` file within the same folder if you use your own xml module and please avoid the path conflict.

then it will work.

Comment: How is __init__.py related to this?

Answer (score 1):

etree package is provided by "ElementTree" and "lxml" both are similar but it is reported that ElementTree have bugs in python 2.7 and works great in python3.
I see you are using python 2.7 so lxml will work fine for you.

try this

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

tree = etree.parse(StringIO(xml_file))
# incase you need to read an XML.

print(tree.getroot())
```

And the StringIO is from default python io package.
StringIO is neccessary when you are passing file to it (I mean putting XML in a file and passing that file to parser).
It's good to keep it even tough you are passing XML as a big string.
all the writing operations will be same for both.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Is the io module necessary? I thought lxml is sufficient.

Comment: @AbdullahNaina
explanation give now.

Comment: I do not want to parse XML instead, I want to create and write XML file.

Comment: @AbdullahNaina, in that case you can use it without StringIO

Comment: when I view the xml file, it does not contain the header, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>?

Comment: @AbdullahNaina
because you are writing it ! how do you expect it to be present. Without writing?

Comment: yes I know that but whenever you open the XML file, at the top of the XML file, there is a version and encoding.